# Front end page submission form does not attach custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, forms, front-end

This side of WordPress is completely new to me, but is also extremely important. I have created a form that allows me to upload a page, with all the parameters I need, however a custom taxonomy is not assigned to the page. However, I need a drop down of all the terms in my custom taxonomy 'walls', so that the user can pick the term and it is assigned to the post.
I have googled and searched on stack exchange and yet none of the code examples I found have worked out for me. 
I have tried the code with categories and it works fine.

Code:

```
<?php if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>

<?php
$postTitleError = '';

if(isset($_POST['submitted']) && isset($_POST['post_nonce_field']) && wp_verify_nonce($_POST['post_nonce_field'], 'post_nonce')) {

if(trim($_POST['postTitle']) === '') {
$postTitleError = 'Please enter a title.';
$hasError = true;
} else {
$postTitle = trim($_POST['postTitle']);
}

$post_information = array(
'post_title' => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['postTitle'])),
'post_content' => esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['postContent'])),
'post_type' => 'page',
'page_template'  => 'Review.php',
'post_status' => 'pending',
'tax_input' => array( 'walls' => array( $_POST['pickWall'] ) ),
);

$post_id = wp_insert_post($post_information);

if($post_id)
{
// Update Custom Meta
update_post_meta($post_id, 'product_aesthetics', esc_attr(strip_tags($_POST['product_aesthetics_meta'])));

wp_redirect(home_url());
exit;
}

}

?>

<?php get_header(); ?>


<!-- #primary BEGIN -->
<div id="primary">

<form action="" id="primaryPostForm" method="POST">

<fieldset>

<label for="postTitle"><?php _e('Post\'s Title:', 'framework') ?></label>

<input type="text" name="postTitle" id="postTitle" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['postTitle'])) echo $_POST['postTitle'];?>" class="required" />

</fieldset>

<?php if($postTitleError != '') { ?>
<span class="error"><?php echo $postTitleError; ?></span>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<?php } ?>

<fieldset>

<label for="postContent"><?php _e('Post\'s Content:', 'framework') ?></label>

<textarea name="postContent" id="postContent" rows="8" cols="30"><?php if(isset($_POST['postContent'])) { if(function_exists('stripslashes')) { echo stripslashes($_POST['postContent']); } else { echo $_POST['postContent']; } } ?></textarea>

</fieldset>


<fieldset>

<label for="product_aesthetics_meta"><?php _e('Product Aesthetics Meta:', 'framework') ?></label>

<textarea name="product_aesthetics_meta" id="product_aesthetics_meta" rows="8" cols="30"><?php if(isset($_POST['product_aesthetics_meta'])) { if(function_exists('stripslashes')) { echo stripslashes($_POST['product_aesthetics_meta']); } else { echo $_POST['product_aesthetics_meta']; } } ?></textarea>

</fieldset>

<fieldset>
<label for="pickWall">Type of wall</label> 
<select name="pickWall">

<?php

// ======= Custom post types category drop down ======== 
$taxonomy = 'walls';
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy); // Get all terms of a taxonomy

if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :

foreach ( $terms as $term ) { 
echo '<option value="' . get_term_link($term->slug, $taxonomy) . '">' . $term->name . '</option>';
}

endif;
?>

</select>
</fieldset>


<fieldset>

<?php wp_nonce_field('post_nonce', 'post_nonce_field'); ?>

<input type="hidden" name="submitted" id="submitted" value="true" />
<button type="submit"><?php _e('Add Post', 'framework') ?></button>

</fieldset>

</form>

</div><!-- #primary END -->

<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should change your input field names to something unique. `category` is a WordPress query var, so submitting a form with that field name may have unexpected results.

That said, `post_category` is only for the `category` taxonomy, custom taxonomies should use the `tax_input` parameter.

**however**... if this form is being submitted by users who are not logged in or don't have the capability to assign terms in your custom taxonomy, then you must use [`wp_set_object_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_set_object_terms) to assign terms after the post is inserted. See the note in [`wp_insert_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post):

> 'tax_input': Equivalent to calling wp_set_post_terms() for each custom taxonomy in the array. If the current user doesn't have the capability to work a taxonomy, the you must use wp_set_object_terms() instead.

EDIT-

for the select field, you can output the term ID as the option value:

```
<?php

// ======= Custom post types category drop down ======== 
$taxonomy = 'walls';
$terms = get_terms($taxonomy); // Get all terms of a taxonomy

if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) :

foreach ( $terms as $term ) { 
    echo '<option value="' . $term->term_id . '">' . $term->name . '</option>';
}

endif;
?>
```

Then when you insert the post:

```
'tax_input' => array( 'walls' => array( $_POST['your_tax_field'] ) )
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I have made the change to the input field names, thanks for the suggestion. Also, I am aware of the tax_input parameter, however I am not sure how to set the term in `array( 'taxonomy' => array('term'))` to the term chosen from the `<select>` taxonomy drop down. Finally, in terms of `wp_set_object_terms` the user will be logged in and will be able to assign the terms.

Comment: see if the edit above answers your question.

Comment: that looks like it should work! I have tried to do that, however it didn't work. Could you clarify for me where this value `your_tax_field` is from. I think I am writing the the wrong value. Thanks!

Comment: `your_tax_field` is whatever you named your select field

Comment: thank you very much for the reply. I have tried this and it does not work!

Comment: do you have any other ideas I can attempt to get this to work, it is really bugging me! Thanks in advance

Comment: update your question with the code you're currently using.

Comment: I have adapted the code in my question to my most recent block of code. Please could you check if there are any obvious problems. Thanks!

Comment: I still have had no luck dispute numerous attempts to fiddle around with it!